# Ionic 3 “phonegap-plugin-push” SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: push-notification, ionic3, cordova-plugin-fcm

I’m building ionic3 application , I’m using phonegap-plugin-push to receive push notifications from FCM , No when I run app on devices it works well on some devices and give me error on others.
any solution for this problem ? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHUCx.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can use ionic fcm cordova plugin https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/
itd much better and easy . push  phonegap-plugin-push is an old version its not working well with the new v of GCM (FCM) that is more modern than old GCM that is deprecated by now

Comment: but with fcm I cannot combine multiple notifications in one notification

Comment: what you mean by combine multiple notifications in one notification

Comment: by the way its more effective and you can do what you need whatever you use in your back-end to manage notifications

Comment: I means my notifications come like whatsApp (multiple notifications grouped under on title)

Comment: i think its ok if the title of notifications is the same it will be stacked as a list under that unique title you sent from your server